# Get iPad version by hardware- which string is for iPad Air/mini?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Using the next code, i am getting the device type. I would like to know also all the device types for iPads( `Air` , and `mini` ).

Is there a new list that includes all the new devices ?
Thanks .

```
- (NSString*)getDeviceType
{
    NSString *hardware = [self hardwareString];
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"]) return @"iPad 3 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"]) return @"iPad 3";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"]) return @"iPad 4 (WiFi)";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"]) return @"iPad 4";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"]) return @"iPad 4 (GSM+CDMA)";

}
- (NSString*)hardwareString
{
    size_t size = 100;
    char *hw_machine = malloc(size);
    int name[] = {CTL_HW,HW_MACHINE};
    sysctl(name, 2, hw_machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *hardware = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:hw_machine];
    free(hw_machine);
    return hardware;
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/InderKumarRathore/UIDevice-Hardware/blob/master/UIDevice%2BHardware.m ?

Answer (score 1):

I have newest Mini Retina (Japanese, with 4G, Model A1490) and it shows iPad4,5 in iTunes.

EDIT: @larme link seems to be perfect https://github.com/InderKumarRathore/UIDevice-Hardware/blob/master/UIDevice%2BHardware.m

Answer (score 1):

This is the new devices which i was looking for .

```
if ([modelIdentifier isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"])      return @"iPad Air (WiFi)";
    if ([modelIdentifier isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])      return @"iPad Air (Cellular)";

    // iPad Mini http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/IPad_mini

    if ([modelIdentifier isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad mini 1G (WiFi)";
    if ([modelIdentifier isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad mini 1G (GSM)";
    if ([modelIdentifier isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad mini 1G (Global)";
    if ([modelIdentifier isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"])      return @"iPad mini 2G (WiFi)";
    if ([modelIdentifier isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"])      return @"iPad mini 2G (Cellular)";
```

Taken from here :
https://github.com/monospacecollective/UIDevice-Hardware/blob/master/UIDevice-Hardware.m